# how to scan for multiple input in a while loop?

Tags: c, while-loop

```
while((player1chip==-1)||(player2chip==-1)||(player3chip==-1)){                                                              
    player1chip=-1; player2chip=-1; player3chip=-1;                                                       
    printf("How many chips would you like to play with (3-10):\n");
    scanf("%d%d%d", &player1chip, &player2chip, &player3chip);
    getchar();
}
```

i want to get 3 values at once but the loop seems has run for 3 times...
how should i do this?

Comment: The loop should execute once and prompt you three inputs and if you all your inputs are not -1, then it should exit. What behavior are you seeing?

Comment: "i want to get 3 values at once but the loop seems has run for 3 times". This sounds like you just want to get the 3 values 1 time? Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Note that `scanf()` will not return until it has read three integers, which need not all be on the same line, or until it fails (because it comes across an alphabetic character, for example).  You should be checking that you get 3 back from `scanf()`; if you get another value, there was a problem.  The `getchar()` will read whatever character was left behind by `scanf()` (e.g. a newline).

Answer (score 0):

```
int p1chip=-1, p2chip=-1, p3chip=-1;
do {
  printf("How many chips would you like to play with (3-10)?\n");
  scanf("%d%d%d", &p1chip, &p2chip, &p3chip);
} while ((p1chip == -1) || (p2chip == -1) || (p3chip == -1))
```

Try that.

Comment: There are numerous ways in which the code can be rewritten to meet this scenario. But, why is the code posted by the user not behaving as expected? The answer should delve on that aspect.

Answer (score 0):

The scanf() statement is a bit strange for what you are trying to do, as you are saying that you are expecting three numbers with no separation by using "%d%d%d".  If the purpose of the while loop is to fill the playerchip variables, you should use an array for them and iterate over the array, like so:

```
playerchip[3];   
for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    printf("How many chips would player %d like to play with (3-10)?:\n", i);
    scanf("%d", &playerchip[i]);
}
```

If you retain your naming scheme, you can't use a loop to fill the variables easily.  To answer you original question though, to grab multiple numbers at once, you need to have some separator in your scanf() statement:

```
scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
```

That way everybody knows when one number ends and another begins.